# "cannot open port!" in a DLL project

Tags: c, dll, serial-port, port

I made a C Console Application in Visual Studio in order to access one of the COM ports with the following code and all went well.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>


/*DWORD dwBytesWrite = 25;
WriteFile(hSerial, "LOOOOOL", n, &dwBytesWrite, NULL);*/
/*
int main(void)
{

int n = 25;
char szBuff[25 + 1] = { 0 };

HANDLE hSerial;
DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };
COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts = { 0 };
DWORD dwBytesRead = 25;

dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(DCB);

hSerial = CreateFile("COM6",
GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
0,
0,
OPEN_EXISTING,
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
0);


if (hSerial == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
if (GetLastError() == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
{
puts("cannot open port!");
return;
}

puts("invalid handle value!");
return;
}

if (!GetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams))
{
puts("error getting state");
return;
}

dcbSerialParams.BaudRate = CBR_9600;
dcbSerialParams.ByteSize = 8;
dcbSerialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
dcbSerialParams.Parity = NOPARITY;

if (!SetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams))
{
puts("error setting port state");
return;
}

timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 30;
timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 100;
timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 100;

if (!SetCommTimeouts(hSerial, &timeouts))
{
puts("timeouts setting fail!");
}

while (1){
if (!ReadFile(hSerial, szBuff, n, &dwBytesRead, NULL)){
puts("serial read error fail!");
return;
}

else
{
printf("%s\n", szBuff);
}
}


getchar();
return 0;

}
```

Now I needed to make a DLL project and it gave me the following error: "cannot open port!"

Any idea why?
Thanks

Comment: Hard-coding the serial port name is a bad idea, it won't be "COM6" on another machine.  If you are 100% sure that the name is correct then keep in mind that there are lots of cr*ppy device drivers out there that don't publish the DOS name.  Use the native device name: "\\\\.\\COM6".

Comment: Yes, i know. But the program is used only in my PC for educational project. I try "\\\\.\\COM6" but the problem persists :(

Comment: Hmm, well, you'll have to educate yourself about Device Manager.  Ask questions about it at superuser.com.